# PHP not connecting to MYSQL via local socket

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, localhost

I have just installed mysql onto my macbook pro, mysql seems to be working, however i cannot connect to mysql from php via mysqli. I keep getting errors. I have read many different articles and web pages, all of which seem complicated and not solving my issue.

I have added /tmp/mysock to the php.ini file:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket= /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I have installed apache, php, mysql all separately and not using software such as MAMP, XAMP, phpmyadmin or MYSQLworkbench

This is my PHP code that is trying to connect to the database, and following the code is the error that is displayed at the browser.

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['blog_title'];
$body = $_POST['blog_entry'];
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','blog');
if (!$link) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}


mysqli_select_db($link,"blog") or die("Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO entires(title,body) VALUES ($title,$body);";
mysqli_query($query);
mysqli_close($link);
header('Location: ViewBlog.php');
exit();
?>
```

This is the error i get:

Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2054 Debugging error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Ive been trying to figure this out for so long, any help would be much appreciated, thanks. 
The database i'm trying to access, i have already created in mysql ("blog");

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue rather than an issue with your code. Have you checked [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Hello tadman, thanks for the tips, in regards to the oo interface, that wouldnt solve the configuration issue that im having. In regards to the warning, this is a beginners project.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the user auth type in MySQL.

I just ran into the same error while setting up wp on Win 10, PHP 7.3 and MySQL 8.0.13.

This was the full error message I was getting:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method
>   unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dbtest.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dbtest.php on line 2 Error: Unable to connect to
>   MySQL. Debugging errno: 2054 Debugging error: The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client

To resolve the issue I had to set the MySQL user to use the standard authentication type.

Here is the SQL Script I ran to fix the issue:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass';
```